# Appending or adding a new row to data frame with index

Tags: python, pandas

How do we add a new series created with a dictionary to an already existing dataframe with a new index.

Initially, I created two series, "series1" and "series2", and then made a dataframe out of the two.

Suppose now I want to add a new row of a particular individual who transacted at the store, "Store 1", calling it "series3" and setting a particular index, "Store 1".

But when I print the series3, it outputs NaN. I am certainly sure that I cannot work this way with dictionary but I cannot seem to reach to a solution.

My ultimate goal is to add a new row with a similar index already existing in the dataframe or create a new one.

How do I approach to add a new row with Series using dictionary? Or is it even possible?

```
series1 = pd.Series({'Name': 'Adam','Age':25, 'Transacted': 'Yes'})

series2 = pd.Series({'Name': 'Mark', 'Age':26, 'Transacted': 'No'})

df = pd.DataFrame([series1, series2], index = ["Store 1", "Store 2"])


series3 = pd.Series({'Name':'John', 'Age':22, 'Transacted': 'Yes'}, index = ["Store 1"])
```

Comment: Note that you have at least one typo in your `series3` line: a missing `'` after `'John`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, but first remove index from `Series` constructor for `series3` and use [setting with enlargement](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement):

```
series1 = pd.Series({'Name': 'Joe',
                    'Age':25,
                    'Transacted': 'Yes'})

series2 = pd.Series({'Name': 'Mark',
                     'Age':26,
                     'Transacted': 'No'
})

df = pd.DataFrame([series1, series2], index = ["Store 1", "Store 2"])
print (df)

series3 = pd.Series({'Name':'John', 'Age':22, 'Transacted': 'Yes'})
print (series3)

df.loc['Store 3'] = series3
print (df)
         Name  Age Transacted
Store 1   Joe   25        Yes
Store 2  Mark   26         No
Store 3  John   22        Yes
```

Or:

```
df.loc['Store 3'] = {'Name':'John', 'Age':22, 'Transacted': 'Yes'}
print (df)
         Name  Age Transacted
Store 1   Joe   25        Yes
Store 2  Mark   26         No
Store 3  John   22        Yes
```

Comment: So, if I try to remove index from series3, and simply create series3 without it. Then create a new dataframe, df_new = pd.DataFrame([df, series3], index = ["Store 1", Store2"], shouldn't this be right? Although, I think it will give Store 1 index to the existing df entries, but that is not my concern right now.

Comment: @pratikwatwani - Not sure if understand, my code not working?

Comment: No, your code is working, but I am more focused on adding an entry with a duplicate index, so for index, "Store 1", I want two entries. Also, I am trying to figure out if what I am thinking is even legit, or it even should work?

Comment: @pratikwatwani - Understand. The best here is append all dictionaries to list of dicts and last call `DataFrame` constructor. Like `df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts)`

Comment: So is there no way to add a new dictionary with a particular column using series?

Comment: Alright, thank you. The approach that I am pursuing seems a little unconventional to me too, but I was interested in knowing if it even works. Thanks!